# "_id" field is set to an int, but bson error is thrown for invalid document key with "."

Tags: pymongo, bson

I'm trying to insert a document into an empty mongoDB (key does not already exist), the bson object has the "_id" field set to an int, but when calling `insert_many`, its throwing an error:

```
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key 'NC_012920.1:8119:C:A' must not contain '.'
```

I understand why documents cannot contain '.', but when printed the document has:

```
{'_id': 8963, ...}
```

Is there a different "key" I'm unaware of?

Why would this string be chosen as the document key?

Full object:

```
{'refsnp_id': '8936', 'create_date': '2000-09-19T17:02Z', 'last_update_date': '2021-04-27T08:18Z', 'last_update_build_id': '155', 'dbsnp1_merges': [], 'citations': [], 'lost_obs_movements': [], 'present_obs_movements': [{'component_ids': [{'type': 'subsnp', 'value': '35324609'}], 'observation': {'seq_id': 'NC_001807.4', 'position': 8120, 'deleted_sequence': 'C', 'inserted_sequence': 'C'}, 'allele_in_cur_release': {'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'position': 8119, 'deleted_sequence': 'C', 'inserted_sequence': 'C'}, 'other_rsids_in_cur_release': [], 'previous_release': {'allele': {'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'position': 8119, 'deleted_sequence': 'C', 'inserted_sequence': 'C'}, 'rsids': ['8936']}, 'last_added_to_this_rs': '125'}, {'component_ids': [{'type': 'subsnp', 'value': '35324609'}], 'observation': {'seq_id': 'NC_001807.4', 'position': 8120, 'deleted_sequence': 'C', 'inserted_sequence': 'A'}, 'allele_in_cur_release': {'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'position': 8119, 'deleted_sequence': 'C', 'inserted_sequence': 'A'}, 'other_rsids_in_cur_release': [], 'previous_release': {'allele': {'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'position': 8119, 'deleted_sequence': 'C', 'inserted_sequence': 'A'}, 'rsids': ['8936']}, 'last_added_to_this_rs': '125'}], 'primary_snapshot_data': {'placements_with_allele': [{'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'is_ptlp': True, 'placement_annot': {'seq_type': 'refseq_chromosome', 'mol_type': 'mitochondrion', 'seq_id_traits_by_assembly': [{'assembly_name': 'GRCh37.p13', 'assembly_accession': 'GCF_000001405.25', 'is_top_level': True, 'is_alt': False, 'is_patch': False, 'is_chromosome': True}, {'assembly_name': 'GRCh38.p13', 'assembly_accession': 'GCF_000001405.39', 'is_top_level': True, 'is_alt': False, 'is_patch': False, 'is_chromosome': True}], 'is_aln_opposite_orientation': False, 'is_mismatch': False}, 'alleles': [{'allele': {'spdi': {'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'position': 8119, 'deleted_sequence': 'C', 'inserted_sequence': 'C'}}, 'hgvs': 'NC_012920.1:m.8120='}, {'allele': {'spdi': {'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'position': 8119, 'deleted_sequence': 'C', 'inserted_sequence': 'A'}}, 'hgvs': 'NC_012920.1:m.8120C>A'}]}, {'seq_id': 'YP_003024029.1', 'is_ptlp': False, 'placement_annot': {'seq_type': 'refseq_prot', 'mol_type': 'protein', 'seq_id_traits_by_assembly': [], 'is_aln_opposite_orientation': False, 'is_mismatch': False}, 'alleles': [{'allele': {'spdi': {'seq_id': 'YP_003024029.1', 'position': 178, 'deleted_sequence': 'L', 'inserted_sequence': 'L'}}, 'hgvs': 'YP_003024029.1:p.Leu179='}, {'allele': {'spdi': {'seq_id': 'YP_003024029.1', 'position': 178, 'deleted_sequence': 'L', 'inserted_sequence': 'M'}}, 'hgvs': 'YP_003024029.1:p.Leu179Met'}]}], 'allele_annotations': [{'frequency': [], 'clinical': [], 'submissions': ['35324609'], 'assembly_annotation': [{'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'annotation_release': 'Homo sapiens Annotation Release 109', 'genes': [{'name': 'mitochondrially encoded ATP synthase 6', 'id': 4508, 'locus': 'MT-ATP6', 'is_pseudo': False, 'orientation': 'plus', 'sequence_ontology': [{'name': '2KB_upstream_variant', 'accession': 'SO:0001636'}], 'rnas': [{'id': 'NC_012920.1', 'codon_aligned_transcript_change': {'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'position': 8119, 'deleted_sequence': 'C', 'inserted_sequence': 'C'}, 'sequence_ontology': [], 'product_id': 'YP_003024031.1', 'hgvs': 'NC_012920.1:m.8120='}]}, {'name': 'mitochondrially encoded ATP synthase 8', 'id': 4509, 'locus': 'MT-ATP8', 'is_pseudo': False, 'orientation': 'plus', 'sequence_ontology': [{'name': '2KB_upstream_variant', 'accession': 'SO:0001636'}], 'rnas': [{'id': 'NC_012920.1', 'codon_aligned_transcript_change': {'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'position': 8119, 'deleted_sequence': 'C', 'inserted_sequence': 'C'}, 'sequence_ontology': [], 'product_id': 'YP_003024030.1', 'hgvs': 'NC_012920.1:m.8120='}]}, {'name': 'mitochondrially encoded cytochrome c oxidase II', 'id': 4513, 'locus': 'MT-CO2', 'is_pseudo': False, 'orientation': 'plus', 'sequence_ontology': [], 'rnas': [{'id': 'NC_012920.1', 'codon_aligned_transcript_change': {'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'position': 8119, 'deleted_sequence': 'CTA', 'inserted_sequence': 'CTA'}, 'sequence_ontology': [{'name': 'coding_sequence_variant', 'accession': 'SO:0001580'}], 'product_id': 'YP_003024029.1', 'protein': {'variant': {'spdi': {'seq_id': 'YP_003024029.1', 'position': 178, 'deleted_sequence': 'L', 'inserted_sequence': 'L'}}, 'sequence_ontology': []}, 'hgvs': 'NC_012920.1:m.8120='}]}, {'name': 'mitochondrially encoded cytochrome c oxidase III', 'id': 4514, 'locus': 'MT-CO3', 'is_pseudo': False, 'orientation': 'plus', 'sequence_ontology': [{'name': '2KB_upstream_variant', 'accession': 'SO:0001636'}], 'rnas': [{'id': 'NC_012920.1', 'codon_aligned_transcript_change': {'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'position': 8119, 'deleted_sequence': 'C', 'inserted_sequence': 'C'}, 'sequence_ontology': [], 'product_id': 'YP_003024032.1', 'hgvs': 'NC_012920.1:m.8120='}]}, {'name': 'mitochondrially encoded NADH dehydrogenase 3', 'id': 4537, 'locus': 'MT-ND3', 'is_pseudo': False, 'orientation': 'plus', 'sequence_ontology': [{'name': '2KB_upstream_variant', 'accession': 'SO:0001636'}], 'rnas': [{'id': 'NC_012920.1', 'codon_aligned_transcript_change': {'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'position': 8119, 'deleted_sequence': 'C', 'inserted_sequence': 'C'}, 'sequence_ontology': [], 'product_id': 'YP_003024033.1', 'hgvs': 'NC_012920.1:m.8120='}]}]}]}, {'frequency': [], 'clinical': [], 'submissions': ['35324609'], 'assembly_annotation': [{'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'annotation_release': 'Homo sapiens Annotation Release 109', 'genes': [{'name': 'mitochondrially encoded ATP synthase 6', 'id': 4508, 'locus': 'MT-ATP6', 'is_pseudo': False, 'orientation': 'plus', 'sequence_ontology': [{'name': '2KB_upstream_variant', 'accession': 'SO:0001636'}], 'rnas': [{'id': 'NC_012920.1', 'codon_aligned_transcript_change': {'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'position': 8119, 'deleted_sequence': 'C', 'inserted_sequence': 'A'}, 'sequence_ontology': [], 'product_id': 'YP_003024031.1', 'hgvs': 'NC_012920.1:m.8120C>A'}]}, {'name': 'mitochondrially encoded ATP synthase 8', 'id': 4509, 'locus': 'MT-ATP8', 'is_pseudo': False, 'orientation': 'plus', 'sequence_ontology': [{'name': '2KB_upstream_variant', 'accession': 'SO:0001636'}], 'rnas': [{'id': 'NC_012920.1', 'codon_aligned_transcript_change': {'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'position': 8119, 'deleted_sequence': 'C', 'inserted_sequence': 'A'}, 'sequence_ontology': [], 'product_id': 'YP_003024030.1', 'hgvs': 'NC_012920.1:m.8120C>A'}]}, {'name': 'mitochondrially encoded cytochrome c oxidase II', 'id': 4513, 'locus': 'MT-CO2', 'is_pseudo': False, 'orientation': 'plus', 'sequence_ontology': [], 'rnas': [{'id': 'NC_012920.1', 'codon_aligned_transcript_change': {'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'position': 8119, 'deleted_sequence': 'CTA', 'inserted_sequence': 'ATA'}, 'sequence_ontology': [{'name': 'coding_sequence_variant', 'accession': 'SO:0001580'}], 'product_id': 'YP_003024029.1', 'protein': {'variant': {'spdi': {'seq_id': 'YP_003024029.1', 'position': 178, 'deleted_sequence': 'L', 'inserted_sequence': 'M'}}, 'sequence_ontology': [{'name': 'missense_variant', 'accession': 'SO:0001583'}]}, 'hgvs': 'NC_012920.1:m.8120C>A'}]}, {'name': 'mitochondrially encoded cytochrome c oxidase III', 'id': 4514, 'locus': 'MT-CO3', 'is_pseudo': False, 'orientation': 'plus', 'sequence_ontology': [{'name': '2KB_upstream_variant', 'accession': 'SO:0001636'}], 'rnas': [{'id': 'NC_012920.1', 'codon_aligned_transcript_change': {'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'position': 8119, 'deleted_sequence': 'C', 'inserted_sequence': 'A'}, 'sequence_ontology': [], 'product_id': 'YP_003024032.1', 'hgvs': 'NC_012920.1:m.8120C>A'}]}, {'name': 'mitochondrially encoded NADH dehydrogenase 3', 'id': 4537, 'locus': 'MT-ND3', 'is_pseudo': False, 'orientation': 'plus', 'sequence_ontology': [{'name': '2KB_upstream_variant', 'accession': 'SO:0001636'}], 'rnas': [{'id': 'NC_012920.1', 'codon_aligned_transcript_change': {'seq_id': 'NC_012920.1', 'position': 8119, 'deleted_sequence': 'C', 'inserted_sequence': 'A'}, 'sequence_ontology': [], 'product_id': 'YP_003024033.1', 'hgvs': 'NC_012920.1:m.8120C>A'}]}]}]}], 'support': [{'id': {'type': 'subsnp', 'value': 'ss35324609'}, 'revision_added': '125', 'create_date': '2005-05-24T13:00Z', 'submitter_handle': 'SSAHASNP'}], 'anchor': 'NC_012920.1:0000008119:1:snv', 'variant_type': 'snv', 'ga4gh': {'NC_012920.1:8119:C:A': {'location': {'type': 'SequenceLocation', 'interval': {'type': 'SimpleInterval', 'start': 8119, 'end': 8120}, 'sequence_id': 'refseq:NC_012920.1'}, 'state': {'type': 'SequenceState', 'sequence': 'A'}, 'type': 'Allele'}, 'NC_012920.1:8119:C:C': {'location': {'type': 'SequenceLocation', 'interval': {'type': 'SimpleInterval', 'start': 8119, 'end': 8120}, 'sequence_id': 'refseq:NC_012920.1'}, 'state': {'type': 'SequenceState', 'sequence': 'C'}, 'type': 'Allele'}, 'YP_003024029.1:178:L:L': {'location': {'type': 'SequenceLocation', 'interval': {'type': 'SimpleInterval', 'start': 178, 'end': 179}, 'sequence_id': 'refseq:YP_003024029.1'}, 'state': {'type': 'SequenceState', 'sequence': 'L'}, 'type': 'Allele'}, 'YP_003024029.1:178:L:M': {'location': {'type': 'SequenceLocation', 'interval': {'type': 'SimpleInterval', 'start': 178, 'end': 179}, 'sequence_id': 'refseq:YP_003024029.1'}, 'state': {'type': 'SequenceState', 'sequence': 'M'}, 'type': 'Allele'}}}, 'mane_select_ids': [], '_id': 8936}
```

I'm sure this is a quick fix, I just dont understand why the '_id' field is no long being treated as the primary key. This  code used to work fine so this could be related to a version change - if that helps at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per the error message You have a key (`NC_012920.1:8119:C:A`) that contains a period (`.`). This isn't allowed.

```
... 'snv', 'ga4gh': {'NC_012920.1:8119:C:A': {'location': {'type': ' ...
```

Comment: Ah, so its not that it's a key for the whole document, or even just a key for an indexed field... its ANY key within the document?

Comment: Yes, any object key.